# Mod rewrite using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to Rewrite my mode using this info[copy from a website], but it's not working .. what's wrong with it and plz give a correct answer..

The Apache rewrite engine is mainly used to turn dynamic url’s such as www.yoursite.com/product.php?id=123 into static and user friendly url’s such as www.yoursite.com/product/123

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Another example, rewrite from:

www.yoursite.com/script.php?product=123 to www.yoursite.com/cat/product/123/

```
RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2
```

Comment: Well, how are you using it in your site? What do current URLs look like etc? Copying code from a site and expecting us to fix it isn't how SO works. Please provide info about your setup and what you've tried

Comment: i am trying in local wampserver, but nothing happend when i visit localhost/abc/product.php?id=23 , it's not changed

Comment: Have you enabled the ModRewrite module in apache for WAMP?

Comment: yaa i did , i enabled it

Comment: did you restart WAMP after enabling? Just trying to eliminate any minor issues causing it

Comment: also, im assuming that your .htaccess file is in the /abc/ folder, right?

Comment: yaa i restarted it many times, even try this on my website but nothing happend, i google it and used some method but no-one working.. i just about to launch my website but i stuck because of this..

Comment: I've posted an idea for an answer. When you say it's not working, can you please provide more details into what actually happens?

Comment: I would also avoid making duplicate posts based on the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what the rewrite module (and your rules specifically) actually does.

Quite simply when you browse to:

```
 localhost/abc/product.php?id=23
```

The RewriteRule isn't invoked and shouldn't be doing anything. There's nothing wrong here, you're just browsing to the **wrong** URL

### URL Transformation

```
http://www.yoursite.com/product/123         <- URL that user goes to
http://www.yoursite.com/product.php?id=123  <- Rewritten URL that the server sees
```

### RewriteRule(s) explanined

A rewrite rule is broken down into *three* parts (not including the `RewriteRule` part...)

1. The regex that it matches against the url
2. The url that it transforms into
3. Additional options

Given your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The regex is: `^product/([^/.]+)/?$`
The new url : `product.php?id=$1`
The options : `[L]`

This means that the user browses to the *nice* url `http://www.yoursite.com/product/123` (and all of your links point to the *nice* URLs) and then the server matches against the regex and transforms it to the new URL that **only the server sees**.

Effectively, this means that you have two URLs pointing to the same page... The *nice* URL and the *not-nice* URL both of which will take you to the same place. The difference is that the *not-nice* / *standard* URL is hidden from  the general public and others pursuing your site.

---

### Regex

The reason why `http://mysite.com/product/image.jpg` is not being redirected is because of the regex that you use in your `RewriteRule`.

#### Explanation

```
^product/([^/.]+)/?$
```

- `^` => Start of string
- `product/` => Matches the literal string `product/`
- `([^/.]+)` => A capture group matching *one or more* characters up until the next `/` or `.`
- `/?$` => Matches an optional `/` followed by the end of the string

Given the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/product/image.jpg
```

Your regex matches `product/image` but then it encounters `.` which stops the matching... As that isn't the end of string `$` the rule is invalidated and thus the transform never happens.

You can fix this by changing your character class `[^/.]` to just `[^/]` or - my *preferred* method - to remove the character class and simply use `.+` (seeing as your capturing everything to the end of the string anyway

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanx all working,,, damn i missed this conecpt... thanx you saved my work

Comment: Can you give an example of a file (css/image) that isn't working?

Comment: all working well , i just need to use change abc/product.php?id=121 to abc/121 and css and images also linked in both types of URLs.. thanx

Comment: but how i do this mysite.com/abc/product.php?id=mypic.jpg into mysite.com/abc/mypic.jpg

Comment: Okay, to clarify, I'm assuming you're using a script to generate the image? So you want users to go to: `http://mysite.com/abc/image.jpg` and then the script to see `http://mysite.com/product.php?id=image.jpg`?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an explanation and solution. Hopefully that makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i used this but still it's not working.. :( :'(

http://localhost/f/product.php?id=121 , nothing happened

Comment: Okay but what isnt working? Are you getting an error? Is it displaying the page? Are you sure you are getting item information based on the $id variable?

Comment: no error, page load as it should.. it's like this code has no effect at all, no error, no change , where should i put this .htaccess file in abc folder or root of localhost

Comment: in abc/ folder. But you shouldnt be going to  localhost/abc/product.php?id=121 you should be going to localhost/abc/product/121