# how can i do Mod Rewrite using .htccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to Rewrite my URL using this code but it's not working. Do 
ou know what is wrong with my code? I want to change the URL as example: `localhost/abc/product.php?id=123` into a static and user friendly URL such as `localhost/abc/product/123`

I've tried this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but also this

```
RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original URL:

http://www.localhost/abc/product.php?id=123

The rewritten URL:

http://www.localhost/123

**USE**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /abc/product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

[Mod Rewrite Tool](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)

Comment: this is not working  , where i put .htaccess in abc folder or main root folder

Comment: main root.public_html

Comment: i did, but not working.. btw thanx for reply.. i think now i have to use ?q this type url :)

Comment: this helped me , i was missing the basic concept...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539848/mod-rewrite-using-htaccess

Comment: @Rishi: In your question you have `static and user friendly URL such as localhost/abc/product/123` but now happy with `localhost/123` ? If you have have mind change its better to update the question otherwise this answer is for a different problem than the stated one.

Answer (score 1):

This rule should work in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(abc)/product/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/product.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```